# FMI (Functional Mock-up Interface): Matlab / Simulink import/export

Tags: simulation, fmi

I would like to use the FMI interface for coupling Matlab and Simulink with other programs. My question: are there openSource FMU import/export packages available? I just find https://www.fmi-standard.org/tools.

Thank you vey much!

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge there are no add-ons that import FMUs into MATLAB/Simulink that are **open source**. For a "free" alternative you can use the Pilot package from the MathWorks. It requires MATLAB/Simulink 2015a or later, https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/181642-can-i-integrate-functional-mockup-units-fmu-with-simulink.

---

**Update September 2017**: MathWorks now provide FMU import (but not export) as a part of Simulink 2017b: https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/in-product-solutions

Comment: FMI Import is now included in the standard release of ML/SL 2017b, see
https://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/release-notes.html